Does $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$ for a continuous function $f$ and normal elements $x,y$ in a C*-algebra?
In words, does a function in the continuous functional calculus behave like a homomorphism? I know that $f^n(x)=f(x)^n$ but that does not help here.

Try the constant function $f(x) = 2$.

Robert already provided a counterexample, but I should mention that the question is ill-posed in the first place - $f(xy)$ does not make sense, since $xy$ may not be normal. Even when it is, for $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ to make sense, you only need $f$ to be defined on $\sigma(x)$ and $\sigma(y)$, but $\sigma(xy)$ needs not be contained in $\sigma(x) \cup \sigma(y)$, so $f$ may not even be defined on $\sigma(xy)$, which is another reason why this doesn’t make sense.
